# How to set the Screenshot directory with Jamf?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, path, mobile-device-management

I'm using Jamf to configure my companies MacBooks and just recently got the request from Management, that every screenshot taken should be placed in a special Directory.

For now, the only thing I found is this:

https://www.maceinsteiger.de/how-to/screenshot-unter-mac-os/

It states that:

> defaults write com.apple.Screencapture location /Users/benutzername;
>   killAll SystemUIServer

can be used to set the screenshot directory. And it works.

Though, are there any other ways to set the directory/path in a non terminal way or with jamf(mdm)?

Comment: Is it alright if the solution involves AppleScript?

Comment: Also. What's wrong with using a Terminal command?

Comment: @oa Yes, AppleScript is also okay and to answer your second question, I simply want a list of alternatives if something doesn't work as expected.